# Неправильно работает функция file()

Tags: php, phpstorm

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <p>Добавить запись в гостевую книгу!</p>
        <input type="text" name="newNot">
        <button type="submit">Добавить</button>
    </form>
    <?php
        include __DIR__ . '/functions.php';
        $fileDir = __DIR__ . '/text.txt';
        $lineArr = file($fileDir, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
        var_dump($lineArr);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

На выходе выводит строку, а должно массив, где 1 строка - 1 элемент
Текст в файл писал вручную. Файл, можно сказать использую вместо базы данных, учусь

Содержимое text.txt:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ccылка на файл: http://rgho.st/private/7GhDm9trK/9ee1a89df4a45b1daa747ca615fca9dc

Comment: какая система? мак?

Comment: У меня Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

До этого я создал текстовый файл через phpstorm. После того как я пересоздал файл обычным методом, то есть через "Рабочий стол" всё заработало, не знаю с чем это связано, может с кодировкой...